# After cloning WP do a subdirectory, I can't access it

Tags: permalinks, redirect, migration

TLDR:

I want to do some work on a WP, but not on the live version (`www.mysite.com`), so I cloned it to a subdirectory `www.mysite.com/new`. Now I am trying to access it, but I get redirected to `www.mysite.com/news/` - news page of the original WP.

---

Here are the steps I took:

- copied `index.php` and `wp` folder to `/new` folder
- created new database and imported everything from the original one
- changed `wp_config.php` of the cloned WP to reflect database changes (different DB name and hostname, different password)
- now, when trying to access `www.mysite.com/new`, I get redirected to `www.mysite.com/news/`, which is the news page of the original WP

Here is the root directory of FTP:

[image]

and here is the `new` directory:

[image]

I know I might need to replace the permalinks with [database search and replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), but at this stage I am at least expecting to see the cloned WP with links pointing to the original WP, not a redirect to `news` page.. 
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the htaccess file and then regenerate it by hitting save at settings->permalinks

Also make sure to change site_url and home (options table), to reflect the updated path.

P.S.: You should really have a local dev env.

Comment: Where do I find Settings->Permalinks? At the original WP control panel? Please note that the original WP must stay the same.

Comment: No, go into "new/wp/" and delete htaccess. Then try accessing yourdomain.com/new/wp/wp-admin ... you'll probably be able to login. Also don't forget to set the new database url to http://yourdomain.com/new/wp

Comment: I was able to access `/new/wp/wp-login.php`, but after logging in, I get redirected to the original admin panel (`www.mysite.com/wp/wp-admin/`).

Comment: Ok, that means you didn't update your database (wp_options table) site_url and home to your updated url as I've instructed.

Comment: wp_options table didn't have these entries, but I did put `define('WP_HOME','siteurlbutSOisblockingit/new/'); ` (same for `WP_SITEURL`) in wp-config.php. Now I can access the cloned WP but it is [without any styles](https://i.imgur.com/8fFdXMl.jpg). Sorry to bother so much, but do you have any clue?

Comment: hmm... did you delete .htaccess? No worries :) Also your full path is /new/wp by looking at your screenshot. Also as a tip: you could have just placed the contents of the wp folder directly into "new", without the index file that you currently have there.

Comment: Holy crap, it works after fixing the url to /new/wp! Thank you so much. About this index.php file, what is it's purpose? It only includes `define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);` and `require('./wp/wp-blog-header.php');`.

Comment: You should have index.php present inside of your theme (so wp-content/theme). The one within the root, just links everything together (so fetches wp-blog-header.php) which then fetches the rest. You'll occasionally see index.php file located in empty folders (or folders with images), and that is just to prevent someone from accessing that folder via the browser. If you need anything else, feel free to shoot over an email (see SO profile). Pa pozdrav iz Kopra :)